# Match text before colon/hypen

Tags: regex

I have strings that can be in following format:

- A: B: C
- A - B - C
- A - B: C
- A: B - C

In all cases, I need to extract everything until `B`, including the colon/hypen and the space following it, so for the examples, that would be following:

- A:
- A -
- A -
- A:

---

For example 1, `^[^:]*:\s*` would work

For example 2, `^[^-]*-\s*` would work

For example 1, 2 and 3, `^([^-]*-|[^:]*:)\s*` would work

I would like something that would give me the desired match for all examples.

Comment: What's the problem with your last regex? As far as I can see, it works for all examples.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It would return "A: B - " for the 4th example instead of the desired "A: "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you can negate multiple characters in square brackets, so just combine your examples 1 and 2

```
^[^:-]*[:-]\s*
```

Matches any characters at the beginning that are no hyphen or colon followed by colon or hypen and spaces, if there are any

https://regex101.com/r/cK6hC7/1

Comment: Excellent answer. The only potential change would be parentheses so that the matched string can be extracted and used, but that depends on what the OP intends to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to avoid using * as to avoid cases with missing starting letters, and make sure to that the regex avoids both : and -

^([^:-]+[:-]\s+)

https://regex101.com/r/sX0zO0/2